# Manual input column with restricted allowed values in power query imported table

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, input, power-query

I'm using the Power Query Editor in Excel in order to obtain a table composed of the content of all the CSV files that I put in a specific folder. This table contains a list of bank transaction. When I'm out of the Editor, having Loaded and Closed the last query modifications, I add a field in this resulting table and I use this field to manually input the categories (e.g. groceries expenses, sport purchases etc) based on the descrition of the transaction. The data validation of this column allows only values listed in a List of Categories that I created for the purpose. It seems though that whenever I add a new CSV in the folder and update my table the category field is messed, I guess because its values have no link with the specific transaction rows that are shifted as new rows are added. How can I have a manual input field, possibly accepting only determined words, in table built with power query folder import.

Comment: Please, if possible, share with us your code.

Comment: In my similar use case I used two tables. One table was the "marked up" table that had dates in it. The other power query/table got the last date from the marked up table and downloaded data after that date. I then just copied and pasted the "new" power query data to the mark up table.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a new "Translation table" with all the search words or phrases in one column (on multiple rows) with the Category for each in a second column.

Then I would build a new Query to read in the "Translation table" - Connection only.

Finally in the main query, I would add a **Merge Queries** step and choose the "Translation table" query, matching your description column to the first column I described above. Check the **Fuzzy Matching** option. You will probably need to set the **Similarity threshold** quite low e.g. 0.3, then set the **Maximum number of matches** = 1. Expand the new table-type column to get the Category as an added column in your main table. The result should be the closest match.

Phrases or collections of words will probably work better than individual words. With Fuzzy Matching solutions, you always have to try lots of different settings and then review the results every time.